# How to extract the value with in the brackets () in Spotfire

Tags: regex, formula, spotfire

How to extract the value within the brackets ()

For example, in the below data set I want to extract the values within the bracket in two separate columns

```
Column 1 -->  aaa / bbb

Column2 --> aaa / ccc
```

Comment: are there always ONLY  two sets of brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two calculated columns. Here are the formulas for each. Just replace `[Column1]` with your column name. This also works if there is only 1 set of parentheses.

**First Set**

```
Substitute(Substitute(Mid([Column1],Find("(",[Column1]),Find(")",[Column1]) - Find("(",[Column1]) + 1),")",""),"(","")
```

**Second Set**

```
Substitute(Substitute(Mid(right([Column1],Len([Column1]) - Find(")",[Column1])),Find("(",right([Column1],Len([Column1]) - Find(")",[Column1]))),Find(")",right([Column1],Len([Column1]) - Find(")",[Column1]))) - Find("(",right([Column1],Len([Column1]) - Find(")",[Column1]))) + 1),")",""),"(","")
```

Comment: Sure you could use that function. Which would be more performant over many rows is something you’d have to check. Regular expressions can be expensive.

Comment: @Raj you'd need to open a new question for that one since it's conditions are different (i.e. there aren't parentheses in both cases)